Understanding 好きで続けているんなら必要なことは全部君の気持ちに必ず追いつく
In the below panel, a man is reassuring a cashier who had a bad day at her work. He told her

好きで続けているんなら必要なことは全部君の気持ちに必ず追いつく

I have difficulty making sense of his wisdom. Does 好きで続けているんなら mean the same thing as 好きでいるんなら? I understood it as "if you keep loving work." Also, what does 君の気持ちに追いつく mean exactly? Literally it means to catch up with your feelings but I am not sure how to interpret it figuratively.


What's your understanding of 必要なこと, and the literal translation attempt of the entire sentence? If the literal translation is correct, interpreting its meaning shouldn't be difficult.

I think I get it now. Thanks anyway.
